# adding a column in R to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, categories

How do I add a column to a dataframe in R based on values in another column of a dataframe ?

For eg if I have one column as x$n = [1,2,3,4,5,6] (values in other colums dont exactly matter. And I want another column as a 'category' column that assigns value 0 if x$n < 2, 1 if x$n is between 3 and 4 and 3 if x$n > 4. So that my corresponding column would be x$category = [0,0,1,1,2,2]

Answer (score 1):

Using `cut`:

```
within(x, category <- as.integer(cut(n,c(-Inf,2,4,Inf)))-1)
```

Using `ifelse`:

```
within(x, category <- ifelse(n>4, 2, ifelse(n>2, 1, 0)))
```

Using implicit boolean -> integer coercion::

```
within(x, category <- (n>2) + (n>4))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
x = data.frame(n = 1:6)
```

and only have three categories, then the easiest solution would be:

```
x$category = 0
x$category[x$n > 2] = 1
x$category[x$n > 4] = 2
```

If you want to be really clever, then you could do:

```
x$category = floor(x$n/2.5)
```

The `floor` function` just rounds down.