# Adding multiple integer ranges of values from a column in the ifelse statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I am dealing with genomic data and I have columns on nucleotide position and its conservation score (in a dataframe). I have data regarding which range of nucleotide positions are introns and which are exons. I want to create a third column and be able to specify which regions are introns (as "INTRON") and which are exons (as "EXON").

As an example suppose in nucleotide positions 1-70000, I want to specify 10000-10200, 17800-21000, 43000-54000 as introns and remaining as exons in another column (hypothetical data). Is there a way of specifying multiple ranges of values from a column in the ifelse function, as that would more or less solve my problem. Is there a better way of doing it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding a column in R to a dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684964/adding-a-column-in-r-to-a-dataframe)

Comment: I think it is more about dealing with range data than adding a column. That said, the OP should be looking at the BioC package 'iRanges'. Doing a search of SO for : { [r] iRanges } should be very helpful since there are many worked examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have data frame like that:

```
 d <- data.frame(position=round(runif(100, 1, 70000)))
```

You can combine logical operators:

```
 d$status <- ifelse(( d$position >= 1000 & d$position <= 10200) | (d$position >= 17800 & d$position <= 21000) | (d$position >= 43000 & d$position <= 54000), 'INTRON', 'EXON')
```

or you can use nested ifelse:

```
d$status <- ifelse(d$position >= 1000 & d$position <= 10200, 'INTRON', felse(d$position >= 17800 & d$position <= 21000, 'INTRON', ifelse(d$position >= 43000 & d$position <= 54000, 'INTRON', 'EXON')))
```

Answer (score -2):

assuming you have a table contain the some information including bmi,
you can use this code

> x$normal_bmi<- ifelse(x$bmi>=18 & x$bmi<= 25,1, 0)

then

> table(x$normal_bmi)

0  1

40 26